# C# WPF - Command Binding of toggle button not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Good day,

I would like to ask question on how to properly bind the RelayCommand UpdateUserCommand() in toggle button. Please see my code below

```
<UserControl x:Class="istock.View.UserMasterList"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:istock.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MinHeight="450" Width="Auto" MinWidth="1024" FontFamily="Segoe UI LIght"> 
<Grid>
    <Border Padding="30 15">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="User Management" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="Auto">
                    <Button x:Name="btnNew" Foreground="#FFFF">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="PlusBoxOutline" Margin="0 5" />
                            <TextBlock Text="New User"  Margin="5 3 5 0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path = UserMasterListProp}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Id}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Username" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Username}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Firstname" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Firstname}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Middlename" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Middlename}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Lastname" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Lastname}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Role" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Role}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Activated">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="tbtnActivated" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton}" IsChecked="{Binding Path = Activated}" Command="{Binding Path = UserViewModel.UpdateUserCommand}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Locked">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="tbtnLocked" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton}" IsChecked="{Binding Path = Locked}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Here is my Command Code which was initialized and CanExecute() method is always true.

```
        public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action ExecuteCmd;
    public RelayCommand(Action paramAction)
    {
        this.ExecuteCmd = paramAction;
    }

   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.ExecuteCmd();
    }
}
```

And Here's my code in ViewModel which the UpdateUser() method will be fired 
by my UpdateUserCommand()

```
      #region Update Command and Method
    private RelayCommand updateUserCommand;

    public RelayCommand UpdateUserCommand
    {
        get { return updateUserCommand; }
    }

    public void UpdateUser()
    {
        try
        {
            var isExist = this.userService.ApplyService_FindByIdOrUsername(UserModel.Id, UserModel.Username);
            if(isExist == null)
            {
                var isUpdated = this.userService.ApplyService_Update(UserModel);
                if (isUpdated == true)
                {
                    this.Message = "Update sucesss.";
                    this.Populate_UserMasterList();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Message = "Update failed. ID or Username already exist.";
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Here is the implementation of the Data Context in Code Behind of the User Control

```
public partial class UserMasterList : UserControl
{
    public UserMasterList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserViewModel userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
        this.DataContext = userViewModel;
    }
}
```

Please help. If ever my code is confusing, I am open for question. Thanks

Comment: `ToggleButton` has a Command property that you can Bind to. Bear in mind that DataContext of datatemplate would need to have that command or you would point it to a datacontext that contains that Command.

Comment: I already point the datacontext in the code behind of the user control but still the command doesn't work. And I just want to add something here, When I test the UpdateUserCommand  in other control like the button, it seems that it is perfectly working. why is that happen and what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind to a property of the parent `UserControl` using a `{RelativeSource}`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="tbtnActivated"
              Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton}"      
              IsChecked="{Binding Activated}"
              Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateUserCommand, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Comment: Hi @mm8. your solution fires up my command however after clicking the toggle button error raise saying "Object reference not set to instance of an object". How can I bind the selected row to my viewmodel? How can I get the value of the first cell ( which is the id ) after clicking the toggle button? thanks

Comment: The system works fine after selecting first a specific row before clicking the toggle button. However I wanted to go straight upon clicking the toggle button. How can I retrieve the record of the selected row in the listview after clicking the toggle button?. thanks

Comment: @user3396413: Your original question was why the command binding didn't work. Not you know why and you have a solution. Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.